# Ignoring commas in c++ cin

Tags: c++, std, cin

I have the following code:

```
float x1 = 0,x2 = 0,y1 = 0,y2 = 0;
cout << "Enter coordinates as \"(x1,y1) (x2,y2)\"\n";
cin >> x1;
cin.ignore(1, ',');
cin >> y1;
cin >> x2;
cin.ignore(1, ',');
cin >> y2;
cout << "Coordinates registered as (" << x1 << "," << y1 << "), (" << x2 << "," << y2 << ").\n";
```

But this always returns (0,0) (0,0).

What would the correct implementation of cin.ignore be?

Comment: You are not eating the parenthesis.

Comment: When you don't know how to use a function in the std namespace (or anything with documentation), look up the reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are literally entering in the data in the form of `(x1,y1) (x2,y2)` like

```
(10,20) (30,40)
```

Then you are going to need to consume the parenthesis as well as the commas.  A simple way to do this is to declare a char variable and use that to get the single characters that need to be removed

```
float x1 = 0,x2 = 0,y1 = 0,y2 = 0;
char eater;
std::cout << "Enter coordinates as \"(x1,y1) (x2,y2)\"\n";
std::cin >> eater; // removes (
std::cin >> x1;
std::cin >> eater; // removes ,
std::cin >> y1;
std::cin >> eater; //removes )
std::cin >> eater; // removes (
std::cin >> x2;
std::cin >> eater; // removes ,
std::cin >> y2;
std::cin >> eater; //removes )
```

To make it a little more compact you can get one coordinate per line like

```
float x1 = 0,x2 = 0,y1 = 0,y2 = 0;
char eater;
std::cout << "Enter coordinates as \"(x1,y1) (x2,y2)\"\n";
std::cin >> eater >> x1 >> eater >> y1 >> eater;
//            (              ,              )
std::cin >> eater >> x2 >> eater >> y2 >> eater;
//            (              ,              )
```

I like to leave the comment in there to to express what should be being consumed each time you get the input.