# How to use fstream to read integers from a csv file

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm struggling with finding a way to have my program read the values of a csv file using the ifstream functionality. This is what I've got so far (I created a new project to try to figure out how to solve this lone problem so there's not much to see for simplicity's sake). One major hurdle I can't seem to get is to elicit the correct numbers from the readStats() function I made. When I run this code as it is, I get a bunch of garbage values. So my question is, how can I correctly read the numbers from the csv file I premade?

NOTE: With other programs I've made, I have not had problems extracting values from CSV files but that was using getline() to retrieve strings. This problem I have here is dealing exclusively with extracting integers.

```
// Reader.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void readStats();
```

```
// Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "Reader.h"

int main() {
    readStats();

    return 0;
}
```

```
// Reader.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "Reader.h"

void readStats() {
    ifstream inputHeroStats("PlayerCharacterStats.csv");
    int heroID, powerLevel, HitPoints, MagicPoints, DexterityPoints, LuckPoints;
    int numberOfStatTypes;
    bool resume = true;

    inputHeroStats >> numberOfStatTypes;
    while (resume) {
        inputHeroStats >> heroID >> powerLevel >> HitPoints >> MagicPoints >> DexterityPoints >> LuckPoints;
        cout << heroID << powerLevel << HitPoints << MagicPoints << DexterityPoints << LuckPoints;
        resume = false;
    }

    inputHeroStats.close();

}
```

and this is all supposed to read from a file I've placed in the project folder called "PlayerCharacterStats.csv" and the values inside that file look like this - acutally, stackoverflow won't let me post a picture because I don't have enough reputation. So I basically have a csv with columns A through F having random integers I placed in there, and 11 rows consisting of more of these arbitrary integers.

What the CSV looks like:

```
0   1   10  25  5   10
1   1   5   30  5   10
2   1   20  15  10  5
3   1   30  0   10  10
4   1   10  15  10  15
5   1   20  10  10  10
6   1   20  0   20  10
7   1   40  0   0   10
8   1   25  0   15  10
9   1   5   5   5   35
10  1   5   5   35  5
```

Comment: It would help if you would show (not describe) what the CSV file actually looks like. If you can't post an image, just copy/paste the actual file text instead. But this code doesn't look like it is attempting to parse a CSV format. For instance, are the columns separated by commas or tabs? Is there a header?

Comment: If you don't want to read the data in as a string and then convert, you can use a solution like I use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33106921/4342498)

Comment: I was trying to paste the values from the csv file here but the site automatically changes it from 6 by 11 to a single line of numbers, like so: 0 1 10 25 5 10
1 1 5 30 5 10
2 1 20 15 10 5
3 1 30 0 10 10
4 1 10 15 10 15
5 1 20 10 10 10
6 1 20 0 20 10
7 1 40 0 0 10
8 1 25 0 15 10
9 1 5 5 5 35
10 1 5 5 35 5

Comment: I recommend updating the question with that example and surrounding it with three backtics (\`\`\`) so that the renderer doesn't try to beautify it. As you can see formatted text comes out looking like a mess in a comment..

Comment: Updated to show the CSV contents, didn't know that I could do that using the backticks.

Comment: Your CSV doesn't look like a CSV. It looks like a tab-separated file. If it is, `std::cout` by default ignores whitespace.

Comment: @Casey it is `operator>>`, not `cin` or `cout`, that ignores whitespace by default

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, typo. It should be `std::ifstream` in this case; also, yes, for correctness it really should be "`std::ifstream`'s `operator >>` be default ignores whitespace."

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not exactly sure what you would like to do with these numbers, the problem with the garbage values is related to the comma values between the integers, which you have not caught.

For this purpose, in fact, a `getline` approach as you mentioned yourself would be better, as you can later use `sscanf` to save your integers from the string.

Otherwise, the below code will successfully save every integer on line 1 of the csv to the respective variable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void readStats()
{
    ifstream inputHeroStats("./PlayerCharacterStats.csv");
    int heroID, powerLevel, HitPoints, MagicPoints, DexterityPoints, LuckPoints;
    char c; //your comma

    inputHeroStats >> heroID 
                       >> c 
                       >> powerLevel 
                       >> c 
                       >> HitPoints
                       >> c
                       >> MagicPoints
                       >> c 
                       >> DexterityPoints 
                       >> c 
                       >> LuckPoints;

    cout << heroID 
            << powerLevel 
            << HitPoints 
            << MagicPoints 
            << DexterityPoints 
            << LuckPoints;
             

    inputHeroStats.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When reading any input, you must check the stream-state following every read of input value to ensure `badbit` or `failbit` are not set. Presuming, as you show, your input is separated by whitespace (space, tab), then at minimum, you would want to do:

```
    while (resume) {
        if (inputHeroStats >> heroID >> powerLevel >> HitPoints >> 
                            MagicPoints >> DexterityPoints >> LuckPoints) {
            std::cout << heroID << powerLevel << HitPoints << MagicPoints << 
                        DexterityPoints << LuckPoints;
        }
        resume = false;
    }
```

Above you only output the values read `if (your_input)` succeeds. You can add an `else { ... }` and handle the error however you choose.

However, note, this is a *Horribly Fragile* approach. Why? If there is any invalid value in your line of input (e.g. a stray characters that is a non-digit and not a leading `+/-`), `failbit` will be set and character extraction from your input stream will cease at that point. You will have no way of knowing which input failed and all inputs from that point forward will be lost. (if you loop attempting to re-read the character that caused the failure, you enter an infinite loop)

You can mitigate that by extracting all characters that remain in that line of input using `.ignore()`. To do so, you need to `#include <limits>` and then add an `else { ... }` to remove all remaining characters for the current line so your next attempted input will pick up at the beginning of your next line of input (instead of re-reading the character that caused the failure and spinning off into an infinite loop if no action is taken)

You would use `.ignore()` as follows:

```
    #include <limits>
    ...
    while (resume) {
        if (inputHeroStats >> heroID >> powerLevel >> HitPoints >> 
                            MagicPoints >> DexterityPoints >> LuckPoints) {
            std::cout << heroID << powerLevel << HitPoints << MagicPoints << 
                        DexterityPoints << LuckPoints;
        }
        else if (inputHeroState.fail()) {
            inputHeroStats.clear();
            inputHeroStats.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        resume = false;
    }
```

Note, above you must check what the failure was to discriminate between a recoverable and unrecoverable failure, see [std::ios_base::iostate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) and [std::basic_ios::rdstate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate). Also note [std::basic_ifstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) provides member function for testing the stream state with `.good()`, `.bad()`, `.fail()` and `.eof()`. You can only recover from `failbit` and you must `.clear()` the error state before continuing.