# C++ user input: python-esque list of tuples to vector of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, c++17, user-input

I require the user to be able to input a Python style list of integer 4-tuples (valid input would be something like `[(1,2,3,4),(56,999,4,3)]`) and have this passed into a `std::vector<std::array<int, 4>>`.

This particular input format is required as users will be providing the input based on the output of another 3rd-party program which gives its output in this manner (Python list of integer valued 4-tuples).

How should one go about doing this? Have the input passed as a string and then perform some kind of regex on the string to extract the integers? Or actually fill the arrays and vector on the fly and somehow watch for the special characters (e.g. '[' begins valid input, ']' end of stream, '(' starts a new 4-tuple, ')' ends the current 4-tuple, etc.)?

External libraries such as Boost are a no-go.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** This seems to do the trick but I don't know if it's "dodgy" in any way...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::array<int, 4>> ans;
    
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    for (char &c : input) {
        if (!isdigit(c)) {
            c = ' ';
        }
    }
    std::vector<int> tmpIntVect;
    std::stringstream ss(input);
    int val;
    while (ss >> val) {
        tmpIntVect.push_back(val);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<tmpIntVect.size(); i+=4) {
        std::array<int, 4> tmpArray;
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            tmpArray[j] = tmpIntVect[i+j];
        }
        ans.push_back(tmpArray);
    }
}
```

Happy to hear any feedback on this approach.

Comment: You are describing fairly simple parsing requirements.  Whether you choose to read a string first, or just read character by character is up to you.  It sounds like you have a couple of ideas already, and nothing should be stopping you from pursuing them.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106519/ignoring-commas-in-c-cin

Comment: What about strtok: https://onlinegdb.com/rJ8NECm8_  The one you editted into your question looks ok too - just be aware that both of them assume the input is valid.

Answer (score 2):

A regex way might look like this(You need a c++11 compiler), I think regex is very helpful to make a parser prototype, then we can focus on the performance turning part(Use parser generator, or rewrite it manually).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <size_t N, typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& oss, const std::array<T, N>& arr) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    oss << arr[i] << ' ';
  }
  return oss;
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& oss, const std::vector<T>& vec) {
  for (const auto& v : vec) {
    oss << v << std::endl;
  }
  return oss;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  const std::string text = "[(1,2,3,4),(56,999,4,3)]";
  std::regex re1(R"'(\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+)'");
  std::regex re2(R"((\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+))");
  std::vector<std::array<int, 4>> arrs;
  std::smatch sm;
  for (auto itr = std::sregex_token_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), re1, 0);
       itr != std::sregex_token_iterator(); ++itr) {
    if (std::regex_match(itr->first, itr->second, sm, re2)) {
      arrs.push_back({std::stoi(sm[1]), std::stoi(sm[2]), std::stoi(sm[3]),
                      std::stoi(sm[4])});
    }
  }

  std::cout << arrs;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick-and-dirty parse for a single line with zero validation that assumes perfect formatting with no whitespace and only positive integers, if you want a jumping-off point:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int LEFT_PAREN = (int)'(';
const int RIGHT_PAREN = (int)')';
const int COMMA = (int)',';
const int ZERO = (int)'0';

int main() {
  string input;
  getline(cin, input);

  auto data = vector<array<int, 4>>();
  auto curr_array = array<int, 4>();
  auto in_tuple = false;
  auto curr_index = 0;
  auto curr_int = 0;

  for (auto i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    auto c = (int)input[i];

    if (isdigit(c)) {
      curr_int = (curr_int * 10) + (c - ZERO);
    }
    else if (c == COMMA && in_tuple) {
      curr_array[curr_index] = curr_int;
      curr_index++;
      curr_int = 0;
    }
    else if (c == LEFT_PAREN) {
      in_tuple = true;
    }
    else if (c == RIGHT_PAREN) {
      curr_array[curr_index] = curr_int;
      curr_index = 0;
      curr_int = 0;

      data.push_back(curr_array);
      curr_array = array<int, 4>();

      in_tuple = false;
    }
  }

  for (auto& i : data) {
    for (auto j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      cout << i[j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `isdigit` to replace `c >= ZERO && c <= NINE` will make your code more clear.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I'll take a look at this. I think I've come up with a solution as well a few minutes ago which I'll edit my post with --- mine is pretty ad-hoc so yours might end up being a better option.